# Error messages for uploading files

Tags: php, wordpress

I keep getting these error messages when using a plug in "üsers ultra pro":

Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in /homepages/2/d644181673/htdocs/app646332697/wp-content/plugins/users-ultra-pro/xooclasses/xoo.userultra.customizer.php on line 227

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/homepages/2/d644181673/htdocs/app646332697/usersultramedia/custom_avatar_image/uultra_default_avatar_image_.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/2/d644181673/htdocs/app646332697/wp-content/plugins/users-ultra-pro/xooclasses/xoo.userultra.customizer.php on line 230

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpTloN3B' to '/homepages/2/d644181673/htdocs/app646332697/usersultramedia/custom_avatar_image/uultra_default_avatar_image_.jpg' in /homepages/2/d644181673/htdocs/app646332697/wp-content/plugins/users-ultra-pro/xooclasses/xoo.userultra.customizer.php on line 230

Warning: getimagesize(/homepages/2/d644181673/htdocs/app646332697/usersultramedia/custom_avatar_image/uultra_default_avatar_image_.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/2/d644181673/htdocs/app646332697/wp-content/plugins/users-ultra-pro/xooclasses/xoo.userultra.customizer.php on line 234

I have checked all the permissions are set to 755 but it still won't work. Any ideas? Thanks :)
Background: I am running a multi user site on Wordpress (think pinterest) where users will be able to upload images/text.

Comment: Any chance you could help me?

Comment: The errors seem pretty clear.

Comment: They might seem clear to you but I cannot fix them. Any clues would be most appreciated. The plug in owners just dumped it and gave me a refund.

Comment: The warning is saying the file doesn't exist at the location. We'd have to see the related code in order to fix that.

Comment: I guess I am asking the impossible here then :(

Comment: If the plug-in owners dumped it consider finding another which will do what you want.